# how to change value of NSColor object into its 8 bit value

Tags: objective-c

I need to convert Value of NSColor object into 8 bit integer value

code :

```
uint8_t r = (uint32_t)(MIN(1.0f, MAX(0.0f, [[CWhiteBoardController ReturnFillColor] redComponent])) * 0xff);

uint8_t g = (uint32_t)(MIN(1.0f, MAX(0.0f, [[CWhiteBoardController ReturnFillColor] greenComponent])) * 0xff);

uint8_t b = (uint32_t)(MIN(1.0f, MAX(0.0f, [[CWhiteBoardController ReturnFillColor] blueComponent])) * 0xff);

uint8_t a = (uint32_t)(MIN(1.0f, MAX(0.0f, [[CWhiteBoardController ReturnFillColor] alphaComponent])) * 0xff);

uint8_t value = (a << 24) | (r<< 16) | (g << 8) | b;
```

value that I received is 0.

i am not getting where I am wrong.
So anyone help me out plz.

Comment: please format your code that it's readable

Answer (score 1):

I come to know the problem,actually I need to write

int value = (a << 24) | (r<< 16) | (g << 8) | b;
in place of
uint8_t value = (a << 24) | (r<< 16) | (g << 8) | b;